# TabControl DevComoponents

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una app Windows Forms, al momento de seleccionar el `tab` por medio de un `If` deseo que cumpla una condición, pero no lo he logrado he probado con este código:

```
private void tabControlCategoriaSubCategoria_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, DevComponents.DotNetBar.TabStripTabChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabCPCategoria.TabIndex == 1)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DGVCategoria;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
        if (tabCPCategoria.TabIndex == 2)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DGVSubCategoria;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

También he probado con este:

```
private void tabControlCategoriaSubCategoria_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, DevComponents.DotNetBar.TabStripTabChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabCPCategoria.TabItem == tabItem1)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DGVCategoria;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
        if (tabCPCategoria.TabItem == tabItem2)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DGVSubCategoria;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

No me ha funcionado con ninguno, antes en otras versiones lo he hecho con `SelectecTab` pero ahora no tiene esa propiedad.

Comment: Pero ¿qué control estás usando exactamente? El XtraTabControl de DevComponents no, porque no tiene ese evento.

Comment: Hola Asier es el TabControl así se llama, ya encontré la solución no estaba poniendo el nombre del control por eso no me salia la propiedad SelectedTab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione.

```
if (tabControlCategoriaSubCategoria.SelectedTab == tabItem1)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DGVCategoria;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
if (tabControlCategoriaSubCategoria.SelectedTab == tabItem2)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DGVSubCategoria;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
```